# jQuery ajax does not submit data via mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, form-submit

I use the following code to submit form data to the database. So, when the option equals keuze, then the data should be added (i.e. data is sent to submit.php). In all other cases, the data should be edited (and thus the data should be sent to edit.php). This all works fine when using chrome on a desktop. But when I try to pass data via safari or chrome mobile, then sometimes data is added or edited successfully, but not always. What could be the problem? The script is shown below.

```
submitformfunction: function(){

     $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(){

        var serialized_data = $(this).serialize();
        var target = $('#busselect option:selected').val();
        var businessid = $('#busselect').children(":selected").attr("id");

        if(target == 'keuze'){


            $(function () {

                $.ajax({

                  type : 'POST',
                  url  : 'submit.php',
                  data : serialized_data,
                  success :  function(data)
                       {
                            alert('Bedrijf toegevoegd');
                       },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        console.log( errorThrown );
                    }
                });

            });

        }
        else
        {


            $(function () {

                $.ajax({

                  type : 'POST',
                  url  : 'edit.php',
                  data : "business_id="+businessid+serialized_data,
                  success :  function(data)
                       {
                            alert('Bedrijf gewijzigd');
                       },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    });

},
```

Comment: Not sure this is causing your issue, but you don't need to wrap your Ajax calls in `$(function(){})`. That syntax is jquery shorthand for "run when document is ready", I.e. when the `onDOMContentLoaded` event has fired)

Comment: Hey Tom tnx for your comment. I tried it without wrapping the Ajax calls in a function without succes.

Comment: As I said, probably not the cause of your issue, but it's worth knowing that you don't need it. In fact, I'm surprised it works at all with the Ajax calls wrapped (AFAIK, onDOMContentLoaded only fires once. Maybe jQuery does some magic and calls the function anyway if it thinks the page had already loaded)

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest using remote debugging (using Safari's develop menu with your mobile device connected via USB) to see whether any JavaScript errors are occurring, or whether the network request triggered by your ajax function is completing successfully

Comment: I found the fix. I had to add "event.preventDefault();" and had to add event to  "$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(event){"